# Python 3.5.1 reading from a file

Tags: python-3.5

I have written a maths quiz for school and the final task requires me to take scores from a file and order them in various ways. I was performing what I thought was a simple task of just writing to a file but it turned out to not work. Can someone please tell me what's missing from this.

```
with open("Class A.txt", "r") as f:
    list(f)
```

Comment: Do you want to read from a file or write to a file?

Comment: Read, I can write perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is already in the format of a list i.e. [1,2,3,4,5], all you have to do is use the eval function. you could try one of the following:

```
with open("Class A.txt", "r") as f: #method 1, requires indentation
    f1 = eval(f.read())
    print(f1)

file = open("Class A.txt", "r") #method 2
f2 = eval(file.read())
file.close()
print(f2)
```

if your string is like this "6|Louis|Perry 2|Shiro|Ski 4|A|B", you could do

```
file = open("Class A.txt", "r")
f2 = file.read().split('|')
file.close()
print(f2)
```

Comment: It comes up with this:

Comment: file_contents_as_list = eval(f)
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: It appears that the eval command is not using the correct data type.

Comment: File "<string>", line 0

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Can I request that you post the contents of the text file

Comment: 6|Louis|Perry
2|Shiro|Ski
4|A|B

Comment: I have tried using delimiters and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> with open("Class A.txt", "r") as f:
...     content = f.read()
...     content_list = content.split('\n')  # split on space/comma/...
```

Read the content and then split it using whichever delimiter you have used, whether enter (\n), comma or anything else.

Comment: This runs the program up until it is supposed to print the scores then just terminates it without displaying them.